# On uniqueness of geodesic between two points on not necessarily complete manifold with nonpositive curvature

Tags: geometry, riemannian-geometry

I know the uniqueness of a geodesic connecting two points on a simply connected manifold $M$ with non-positive sectional curvature can be proven easily with Cartan-Hadamard theorem under the assumption that $M$ is complete. How can I go about proving this statement if the completeness of $M$ is NOT assumed?

To clarify, I'm trying to prove when $M$ is a manifold as above (simply connected, nonpositive sectional curvatures, but NOT necessarily complete), then there can be at most one geodesic between any two distinct points.

Comment: I didn't get your question. What do you want to prove?

Comment: What happened if you remove a point from $\mathbb H^3$?

Comment: I'm trying to show that there can be at most one geodesic connecting two points on $M$ if $M$ is a manifold that is simply connected, has nonpositive curvatures, but is not necessarily complete.

Comment: Also the statement still holds for $\mathbb{H}^3 \setminus \text{origin}$ if you were thinking about two semicircles connecting, say $(1,0,0)$ and $(-1,0,0)$. The geodesic in that case simply doesn't exist.